# Is there a way to create nice installable applications with GUI and hard lock licenses from python just like we create in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, ironpython, nsis, py2exe, pyinstaller

I am familiar with cx_freeze, py2exe and pyInstaller that convert python scripts to executable programs which can be further bundled with NSIS as windows installers.

But I have run into issues with these tools:
1. with some python modules like pandas and SimpleCV, executables give errors which I have tried to resolve through module developers as well as developers of the above tools but to no luck.

Is there a way to create nice installable applications with GUI and hard lock licenses from python just like we create in Visual Studio?

Or would I have to rewrite my python program in Csharp or CPP etc.?

I hope someone can answer, I am not sure if IronPython would help in this regard?

**EDIT :** I tried IronPython, but with 2.7 I cannot import many python modules like the one I mentioned. If someone knows better, please guide....

Comment: If you write your application in IronPython, not only will you be able to create an installer for it, but you will also have access to the .NET Framework, a better threading model, and arguably better performance than some Python interpreters.

Comment: Thanks Robert for answering, I am wondering if I can import the modules like I do in my python installation?
My script depends on the modules, in this case, these are Image processing modules like openCV, SimpleCV, PIL, pygame etc...

Comment: That's a good question.  It wouldn't be that hard to try them.

Comment: So I installed IronPython and tried importing these modules, but they are not visible to the IronPython interpreter.
Either I have to install them in IronPython or if I can somehow have one file being interpreted by standard python interpreter, it might work!!

Comment: More likely, you will have to use the source code from those modules. SimpleCV and the like are not .NET assemblies out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to integrate NSIS and Visual Studio use this third party addon called **Visual & Installer**: http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/visual-installer/index.html

Working fine with Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 and 2012.

Comment: Please state your affiliation with the mentioned product.